# How do I stop the colorcolumn from breaking into multiple pieces when there are wrapped lines?

Tags: colorcolumn

The colorcolumn works well when there are no wrapped lines. `set colorcolumn=80`:

[image: Vim colorcolumn]

However, when there are long lines that are wrapped, the colorcolumn breaks into multiple pieces:

[image: Vim colorcolumn on wrapped lines]

Is there a way to make it such that the colorcolumn will always be a single unbroken line?

Answer (score 4):

The `colorcolumn` setting accepts multiple values, for example `set colorcolumn=30,60` will highlight column 30 and 60.

We can use this to display a single unbroken line for wrapped lines; for example for a 130-column line on a 40 column wide display you would use `set colorcolumn=30,70,110` to highlight the first three columns.

You can set this automatically with a little command:

```
command! -nargs=1 WrappedCC let &colorcolumn = join(map(range(10), {i -> &columns * i + <args>}), ',')
```

This uses `&columns` to get the screen width, and adds the first ten colour columns at the correct place.

---

You can also hook in to `OptionSet` autocommand to automatically do this whenever `colorcolumn` is set, so you don't need a new command; you can just use `set cc=80` instead of `WrappedCC 80`. You can still use `set cc=` to clear the highlight, or `set cc=80,120` to only set those two columns.

```
fun s:wrapped_cc()
    let &colorcolumn = join(map(range(10), {i -> &columns * i + str2nr(&cc)}), ',')
endfun

augroup wrappedcc
    autocmd!
    autocmd OptionSet  colorcolumn  if &cc != '' && &cc !~ ','       | call s:wrapped_cc() | endif
    autocmd VimEnter   *            if &cc != '' && &cc !~ ','       | call s:wrapped_cc() | endif
    autocmd VimResized *            if len(matchlist(&cc, ',')) >= 4 | call s:wrapped_cc() | endif
augroup end
```

This also needs to hook in to the `VimEnter` because `OptionSet` isn't triggered on startup; otherwise `set colorcolumn=80` from your vimrc won't work; since the `VimEnter` is triggered after reading all the vimrc you can put the `set colorcolumn=` anywhere in your vimrc (it doesn't need to be after the autocmd).

Also need to hook in to the `VimResized` to re-calculate the column positions because they need to be adjusted after the window is resized. This assumes that anything with more than four columns is a "wrapped column".

Comment: Note: just noticed this will break `set cc=+1` to set the colour column relative to the text width. I'll leave this answer as-is for now; I'll fix it later.

Comment: Martin, thanks a lot for updating the answer. Just in case, there is still one issue here - the columns don't match if there is `set number`.

Comment: It seems it should be `i -> (&columns - &numberwidth)` instead of `i -> &columns` to fix this.

Comment: Right @johnc.j., although that will break if you don't have any numbers enabled. Also if you have any placed signs that needs to be subtracted. Getting the actual "editable" window width seems somewhat non-trivial 

Comment: I have just discovered that to make this function work properly, `colorcolumn` must be set with absolute value: `set columns=100 textwidth=78 colorcolumn=79` or by using `let`: `let &colorcolumn = &textwidth + 1`. If you use `set` with relative number, the function won't work properly (`set colorcolumn=+1  " the function will work wrong`).