# 'autocmd OptionSet' - How to make it work?

Tags: vimrc, autocmd

The following .vimrc snippet is by Martin Tournoij's answer posted here: [How do I stop the colorcolumn from breaking into multiple pieces when there are wrapped lines?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28968/how-do-i-stop-the-colorcolumn-from-breaking-into-multiple-pieces-when-there-are)

```
augroup wrappedcc
    autocmd!
    autocmd OptionSet colorcolumn
        \  if &cc != '' && &cc !~ ','
        \|   let &colorcolumn = join(map(range(10), {i -> &columns * i + &cc}), ',')
        \| endif

    autocmd VimResized *
        \  if len(matchlist(&cc, ',')) >= 4
        \|   let &colorcolumn = join(map(range(10), {i -> &columns * i + str2nr(&cc)}), ',')
        \| endif
augroup end
```

Could anybody explain why it doesn't work unless I type `:set cc=78` in command mode?

That is, why it doesn't work if I simply add `set cc=78` before or after it **in the .vimrc itself**?

#### An update for Vivian De Smedt

Here is my test .vimrc:

```
augroup wrappedcc
  autocmd!
  autocmd OptionSet colorcolumn
      \  if &cc != '' && &cc !~ ','
      \|   let &colorcolumn = join(map(range(10), {i -> &columns * i + &cc}), ',')
      \| endif

  autocmd VimResized *
      \  if len(matchlist(&cc, ',')) >= 4
      \|   let &colorcolumn = join(map(range(10), {i -> &columns * i + str2nr(&cc)}), ',')
      \| endif
augroup end

set colorcolumn=78
```

I also tried to put `set colorcolumn=78` above the augroup instead of below it.

And here is a test file, colorcolumn-test.txt:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

When I start Vim, `:set cc?` returns `78` and there is only one color column, at 78:

[image]

```
:set cc?
=> 78
```

Then, if I type `:set cc=78` in command mode, this fixes the issue:

[image]

```
:set cc?
=> 78,158,238,318,...
```

Vim 9.0 on Windows.

Comment: The `OptionSet` event isn't triggerd on Vim startup (this is documented, so the expected behaviour); I didn't know that! I updated my original answer to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `VimEnter` `autocmd` to correct the `colorcolumn` setting after the `.vimrc` is read.

```
augroup wrappedcc
  autocmd!
  " Correct the settings after VimRC is read:
  autocmd VimEnter *
      \  if &cc != '' && &cc !~ ','
      \|   let &colorcolumn = join(map(range(10), {i -> &columns * i + &cc}), ',')
      \| endif

  " Correct the settings after colorcolumn is changed:
  autocmd OptionSet colorcolumn
      \  if &cc != '' && &cc !~ ','
      \|   let &colorcolumn = join(map(range(10), {i -> &columns * i + &cc}), ',')
      \| endif

  " Correct the setting each time the window is resized:
  autocmd VimResized *
      \  if len(matchlist(&cc, ',')) >= 4
      \|   let &colorcolumn = join(map(range(10), {i -> &columns * i + str2nr(&cc)}), ',')
      \| endif
augroup end
```

```
set colorcolumn=78
```

Comment: Well, but this doesn't answer my question. The only problem I have with this snippet is that it works if I start Vim and then type `:set cc=78` in command mode. **But** it doesn't work if I add `set cc=78` before or after it **in .vimrc itself**.

Comment: It should :-) Could you share your .vimrc ? Could you try to set cc at the end of it? What is the result of the command `set cc`? It seems to mz that some part of your .vimrc unset cc.

Comment: See the updated question :-)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is your `set cc` positioned after the `autocmd`?

Comment: Yes, see my test .vimrc that I posted in the update :-)

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. I'll search for a solution :-)

Comment: It seems it was simply required to replace `OptionSet colorcolumn` with `autocmd BufReadPost,BufNewFile *`. Duh...

Comment: I had the same idea ;-). I believe `VimEnter` consume slightly less processing time and seems to work fine.